# Ubuntu 11 Desktop without an administrator user

Tags: ubuntu, unix, sudo

Somehow I managed to change my user to a "standard" account, as opposed to an administrator account, and I don't have any access to sudo, or a backdoor account with admin rights.

Is there anyway I can fix this without having to rebuild the entire machine?

Answer (score 1):

You can try entering the emergency recovery mode.

Alternatively, boot from a CD or DVD, and mount the drive (say, to `/media/hdd`). Then, enter the old system via a [chroot](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Chroot) with

```
sudo chroot /media/hdd
```

Once you're in - either via emergency recovery mode or CD/chroot -, fix the problem by editing `/etc/sudoers` (for example, with the command `visudo`).

It should read like

```
Defaults env_reset
root  ALL=(ALL) ALL
%sudo ALL=(ALL) ALL
```

Also, make sure that your user is still in the `sudo` group, with the command

```
usermod -G sudo -a travis
```

(Most likely, you executed `usermod -G` without the `-a` parameter if that's the case).

You can try out sudo by typing `su travis`, and then `sudo -s`. If `sudo` fails, type `exit` (or press <kbd>Ctrl</kbd>+<kbd>D</kbd> to get back to your root shell. After you've fixed the problem, simply reboot your old system (remove the CD/DVD beforehand) and everything should work again.

Answer (score 0):

Easy way to fix this is to reboot and log into single user mode.
To do that you need to press "Esc" before GRUB starts and on the kernel line
type "single" or "1".